# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http ... (with plain HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

I have been receiving the following error since I started learning AngularJS:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ToDo&p1=Error%3A%20…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A315)
```

In my efforts to debug this error, I started stripping down my HTML script by script until I was left with an empty HTML that only contained `ng-app` declaration and `<script>` to import the `angular.min.js` via CDN.

Please Help !!

Here's what my html looks like::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some AngularJS JavaScript codes.

Answer (score 0):

Made a silly mistake, 
the `<script>` has to go within the `<body>` tags. Here is what solved the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>Obligatory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
</html>
</body>
```

I guess I was more more dumb that I had anticipated :)